# I have to display the column name with highest value in a row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
COUNTRY     NUM_GUNS MAX_BOR  MAX_DISP
Gt.Britain  40000    45000    32000
Germany     40000    45000    42000
USA         60000    48000    46000
Japan       45000    54000    65000
```

This is my table and i need column name with highest value in the row.Example for Gt.Britain the max value is 45000 i want to display it as max_bor.

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to display 4500 as max or you want to display column name like `max_bor`?

Comment: i want to display max_bor

Comment: For the maimum value in the row i need to display its column name..

Comment: @user3743684 Can you provide the sample output

Comment: COUNTRY     MAX_VAL  NAME
Germany     45000  max_bor
Gt.Britain  45000  max_bor
Japan     65000  max_disp
USA     60000  num_guns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try do it *explicitly*, like that:

```
select case 
         when NUM_GUNS = Greatest(NUM_GUNS, MAX_BOR, MAX_DISP) then
           'NUM_GUNS'
         when MAX_BOR = Greatest(NUM_GUNS, MAX_BOR, MAX_DISP) then
           'MAX_BOR'  
         else
           'MAX_DISP'  
       end as MaxColumnName,
       Greatest(NUM_GUNS, MAX_BOR, MAX_DISP) as MaxColumnValue   
  from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` Statement

```
SELECT COUNTRY,
       CASE WHEN NUM_GUNS > MAX_BOR AND NUM_GUNS > MAX_DISP THEN 'NUM_GUNS' ELSE NUM_GUNS END NUM_GUNS,
       CASE WHEN MAX_BOR > NUM_GUNS AND MAX_BOR > MAX_DISP THEN 'MAX_BOR' ELSE MAX_BOR END MAX_BOR ,
       CASE WHEN MAX_DISP > MAX_BOR AND MAX_DISP > NUM_GUNS THEN 'MAX_DISP' ELSE MAX_DISP END MAX_DISP 
FROM YourTable
```

*Output:*

---

```
    COUNTRY     NUM_GUNS MAX_BOR  MAX_DISP
    --------------------------------------
    Gt.Britain  40000    MAX_BOR  32000
    Germany     40000    MAX_BOR  42000
    USA         NUM_GUNS 48000    46000
    Japan       45000    54000    MAX_DISP
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query gives the result of column containing max value

```
`SELECT t.country, 
(CASE
    When t.NUM_GUNS >= t.MAX_BOR 
        then (case when t.NUM_GUNS >= t.MAX_DISP then t.NUM_GUNS else t.MAX_DISP)
    When t.MAX_BOR >= t.MAX_DISP
        then (case when t.MAX_BOR >= t.NUM_GUNS then t.MAX_BOR else t.NUM_GUNS)
    when t.MAX_DISP >= t.NUM_GUNS
        then (case when t.MAX_DISP >= t.MAX_BOR then t.MAX_DISP else t.MAX_BOR))
as max_column

from country_table as t
order by t.country`
```